# Enable PHP on a specific html page in a specific directory

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have a Rackspace Cloud Sites account and I'm trying to enable PHP for a single html file in a specific directory under my root site folder.

I have a .htaccess file in my root folder. And my document root from using `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` is `/mnt/stor1-wc2-dfw1/myaccnum/servernum/mydomain.com/web/content`(I've obscured a few details but the basic structure is intact).

I then do the following (which I saw on another SO answer):

```
<Directory "/mnt/stor1-wc2-dfw1/myaccnum/servernum/mydomain.com/web/content/mydir">
  <Files "index.html">
    AddType application/x-httpd-php .html .htm
  </Files>
</Directory>
```

However, I'm getting error "500 Internal Server Error". If I take away `<Directory>` and `<Files>` everything works but for all files.

How can I fix this?!

Comment: what does your apache log say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot add types per directory or location. However, you can manipulate the [`engine`](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/apache.configuration.php#ini.engine) ini setting of PHP. Set it to `off` globally and enable it only for your index.html.